# c# load image from external dll

Tags: c#, embedded-resource

After many hours on Google and here, i ask yours help, because not found any valid solution, but only wrong way.

I have many images into a dll as embedded resource, add this dll as reference to my application and need use this images into my application.
What is the fastest way to do this? Any sample?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Visual Studio go to the project properties of your dll and then to the tab resources. Change the access modifier from internal to public to make the resources easy accessible for your application.

[image]

In your application add a reference to your dll and access the images via the public resource class of the dll.
Example for assign an image to a pciture box in your application:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = ClassLibrary1.Properties.Resources.SamplePicture;
    }
```

Comment: Fantastic solution, works fine. Thank you very much!